# Webcenter Sites REST API: How to add multiple attributes on asset?

Tags: java, rest, fatwire, webcenter-sites

I've created an asset with a multiple attribute, like for instance, a set of images.

I would like to insert images to that asset with Webcenter Sites REST API but I don´t know how.

Single attribute is like this:

```
sourceAssetAttribute = new Attribute();
  sourceAssetAttributeData = new Data();
  sourceAssetAttribute.setName("FSIILongDescription");
  sourceAssetAttributeData.setStringValue("Test Long Description");
  sourceAssetAttribute.setData(sourceAssetAttributeData);
  sourceAsset.getAttributes().add(sourceAssetAttribute);
```

And multiple is how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it.

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=563491042188574&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1528601.1&id=1510322.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=m55lxhl4z_58

It´s like this:

```
sourceAssetAttribute = new Attribute();
  sourceAssetAttributeData = new Data();
  sourceAssetAttribute.setName("attribute_name");

sourceAssetAttributeData.getStringLists().add(0,"Asset_type:"+asset_id));
sourceAssetAttributeData.getStringLists().add(1,"Asset_type:"+asset_id));

sourceAssetAttribute.setData(sourceAssetAttributeData);
sourceAsset.getAttributes().add(sourceAssetAttribute);
```